# Action view error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have some code ..

```
<% @articles.each do |article|%>
   <%= link_to h(article.title), show_article_path({:id => article.permalink})%></font>
<% end %>
```

i have 3 action use this code, but i want to get result only between start_publish and finish_publish or finish publish blank and (only in one action for example Action Posting), then i added code like this

```
<% @articles.each do |article|%>
  <% if (Time.now >= article.posted_at) && (Time.now <= finish_publish || article.finis_publish.blank?) && (params[:action] =>'posting')%>
    <%= link_to h(article.title), show_article_path({:id => article.permalink})%>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to h(article.title), show_article_path({:id => article.permalink})%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

this is worked when fields arent blank. the problem is when finish publish blank, appear error message. it said .. Time.now value nil. and i think "&& (params[:action] =>'posting')%>" is error.

please have You suggestion for this case?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do.  The exact same code is run whether or not your conditions are met and you seem to have typos in the code you posted.  

Can you post the actual code from your view as well as the full text of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to do `params[:action] == "posting"` The `=>` syntax is known as the hash rocket, which assigns a key to a value inside a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Time.now try creating a time object:

```
today = Time.new
```

and then check against "today" and not "Time.now"